# Verbs of perception - Infinitive

Tags: grammar

Verbs of senses:

1. I see him work in the garden.
2. I see him working in the garden.
3. I see him be in the garden (wrong) => I see that he is in the garden.

Other verbs:

4. I consider him to work in the garden.           Wrong
5. I consider him to be working in the garden.
6. I consider him to be in the garden.                Wrong

But:     I consider him to be a promising writer. – correct
Sentence 3 is clear – to be doesn’t allow to follow a general rule with verbs of senses.
Do all other verbs allow to use such a construction when the Object Complement is expressed as a NP only, as in sentence 5?

Why 4 and 6 are wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not convinced #6 is "wrong". It just might imply a *slightly* contrived context (perhaps he's standing right on the boundary of my property, and although ***in my opinion*** he's "in the garden", someone else might say he's actually "in the street" outside my house). The "rule" here is that if you ***consider** [someone] **to be** [something adverbial or adjectival]* this must be ***a matter of opinion***. As opposed to the normal *I think he's here*, where my assertion can only be true or false (it's not a "judgement / assessment" call).

Comment: ...so although it's perfectly okay to say *I **think** the Sun is 93 million miles away from Earth,* you can't naturally say  *I **consider** the Sun to be 93 million miles away from Earth*. That's because even if I personally am unsure of the exact distance, at least I know that either the assertion is true or it isn't - there's simply no scope for anyone to think anything different.

Comment: FumbleFingers, thank you a lot! Would it be right to use To be-Infinitive with verbs of NON-perception as in : Mary thought she was grown up. => mary thought herself to be  a grown up.??? thank You!

Comment: I think you've got it. But see [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+considered+himself+to+be%2CHe+thought+himself+to+be&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHe%20considered%20himself%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHe%20thought%20himself%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0)...

Comment: ...and [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=considered+himself+to+be+alone%2Cthought+himself+to+be+alone%2Cthought+he+was+alone&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthought%20himself%20to%20be%20alone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthought%20he%20was%20alone%3B%2Cc0)...

Comment: ...and [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+considered+himself+to+be%2CHe+thought+himself+to+be%2CHe+thought+he+was&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHe%20considered%20himself%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHe%20thought%20himself%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHe%20thought%20he%20was%3B%2Cc0) - showing that if you're going to use that "subjunctive" ***to be*** construction, the verb ***consider*** is far more likely than ***think***. But overall, the most common usage is simply *She **thinks** she's grown-up*.